# Как реализовать HashSet?

Tags: java

Мне нужно реализовать `HashSet<Region>`. Если просто добавить в хэшсет 2 одинаковых объекта класса `Region` (с одни и тем же значением `value`), то в хэшсете будут лежать оба объекта, а не один. Как этого избежать? Как сделать так, чтобы не добавлялись объекты, одинаковые по полю `value`. И как в такой сете установить наличие или отсутствие другого экземпляра класса? (`сontain` не прокатывает).
Вот класс `Region`

```
public class Region {

private Regions value;

public Regions getValue() {
    return value;
}

public void setValue(Regions value) {
    this.value = value;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    Region otherRegion = (Region) obj;
    return this.value.equals(otherRegion.getValue());
}

static enum Regions {
    region1("region - 1"),
    region2("region - 2"),
    region3("region - 3"),
    region4("region - 4");

    private String value;

    Regions(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
    public String toString() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

}

================================================

```
        HashSet<Region> q = new HashSet<Region>();
    Region qwe1 = new Region();
    qwe1.setValue(Region.Regions.region1);
    Region qwe2 = new Region();
    qwe2.setValue(Region.Regions.region1);
    q.add(qwe1);
    q.add(qwe2);

    Region qwe3 = new Region();
    qwe3.setValue(Region.Regions.region2);

    out.println(qwe1.equals(qwe2));
    out.println(q.size());
    out.println(q.contains(qwe3));
```

А вот, собственное результат:

```
true
2
false
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для корректной работы HashSet<Region> Вам необходимо переопределить метод equals в классе Region. Т.е. показать, что с Вашей точки зрения является эквивалентностью регионов.

Также, для более быстрого доступа к объектам в Set (путём избегания коллизий), переопределяют метод hashCode. Но это в том случае, если у Вас есть свой собственный уникальный идентификатор (id из базы данных, например). Вам сейчас не обязательно.

equals, hashCode вызываются внутри HashSet при попытке добавления объекта.

Ещё по вашему коду: зачем в классе Region enum этих регионов?
Просто сделайте поле

```
private String name;
```

как название региона.

И в методе equals сравнивайте по нему:

```
@Override
boolean equals(Object otherObj) {
    // Каст к Region
    Region otherRegion = (Region) otherObj;

    // Обязательно проверки на null
    // instanceof, равенство ссылок на объект
    return  this.name.equals(otherRegion.getName());
}
```

И потом, добавляйте регионы в Set:

```
HashSet<Region> regions = new HashSet<Region>();

Region reg1 = new Region();
reg1.setName("East");
Region reg2 = new Region();
reg2.setName("West");
Region reg3 = new Region();
reg3.setName("East");

regions.add(reg1);
regions.add(reg2);
regions.add(reg3); // Не добавится
```

Comment: Энум регионов нужен для того, чтобы они принимали определенное значение, а не просто абстрактное String.

А откуда тип Object знает метод getName()?

Comment: Верно. Забыл каст к Region. Поправил.

Comment: И что-то все-равно не получается...
Как и прежде могу добавить 2 одинаковых Region в сет и, кроме того, contains выдает fallse, когда должен выдавать true - добавил код.

Comment: Метода equals было достаточно для случая, когда я предлагал ввести String name. 

Но сейчас, когда Вы оставили enum Regions, настало время для hashCode :-)
Добавляйте в Region:

 @Override
 public int hashCode() {
  return this.value.toString().hashCode();
 }

Без этого метода хэш-код для элемента генерировался каждый раз разный (native метод Object). Теперь для каждого элемента enum возвращается одинаковый.

Comment: ага, работает, спасибо!!!!
Как думаете - стоит оставить энум в классе или лучше его вынести?

Comment: Всё зависит от конкретной задачи и условий. Но на первый взгляд, такая конструкция нелогична. В классе, описывающей Регион (Это может быть и Европа, и Азия), уже содержатся разные регионы - таже Европа, Азия, Америка. Лучше enum вынести из класса (можно даже в отдельный файл) и использовать как отдельный класс:

  Region qwe1 = new Region();
  qwe1.setValue(Regions.region1);
  Region qwe2 = new Region();
  qwe2.setValue(Regions.region1);